# Code optimization help needed, as it is getting stuck in serial operation

Tags: python, loops, optimization

I am writing a code to randomly generate some spots in a defined region (and storing their x,y co-ordinates) and moving and growing them into triangles in subsequent time steps (and storing the x,y co-ordinates of the 3 corners and time) at all time steps. The time step DT is of the order of 1 microsecond. For smaller time scales (TIME_MAX), the code below works. For TIME_MAX larger than 0.005, it is getting stuck/hung in the GROW function as it consumes a lot of CPU time and still doesn't generate the required output. Since it is running in serial mode, I was wondering if there is any way of speeding this up - either by different looping techniques or some array modifications or some other optimization method. I would like to at least be able to run this until TIME_MAX = 1 on a standard, single core of a CPU. Any help would be much appreciated. Thanks in advance!

The code is as below:

```
import math
import random
import numpy as np

# Initializations
####
ui = 4138
x_length = 2.0 
y_width = 1.0 
xtro = 0.5 
ule = 3724 
ute = 2069
alfa = 1.31
xsgs = xtro
xsge = xsgs + 0.1*xsgs
INDEX = 0
TIME = 0 
DT = 0.000001
TIME_MAX = 1.0
GROW = []
DOTS = []
####


def init(TIME, xsgs, xsge, y_width):
    PX = xsgs + random.random()*(xsge-xsgs)
    PY = y_width*random.random()
    TIME_FORM = TIME
    DOTS.append([PX, PY, TIME_FORM])
    return(DOTS[:])

def grow(INDEX, TIME, TIME_FORM, PX, PY, ute, ule, alfa):
    X1 = PX + ule*(TIME-TIME_FORM)
    Y1 = PY 
    X2 = PX + ute*(TIME-TIME_FORM)
    Y2 = PY + ute*(TIME-TIME_FORM)*math.tan(alfa)
    X3 = PX + ute*(TIME-TIME_FORM) 
    Y3 = PY - ute*(TIME-TIME_FORM)*math.tan(alfa)
    if X2 < 1.5 and Y2 < 0.5 and Y3 > 0:    
        GROW.append([INDEX, TIME, TIME_FORM, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3])     
    return (GROW[:])


while TIME<TIME_MAX:
    Y_N = random.random()
    if Y_N < 0.1:
        DOTS = init(TIME, xsgs, xsge, y_width)
    TIME = TIME+DT
    for j in range(len(DOTS)):
        PX = DOTS[j][0]
        PY = DOTS[j][1]
        TIME_FORM = DOTS[j][2]
        INDEX = TIME_FORM/DT
        GROW = grow(INDEX, TIME, TIME_FORM, PX, PY, ute, ule, alfa)
DOTS = np.array(DOTS)
np.savetxt('gen_dump.txt', DOTS, fmt = '%10.12f', delimiter=',', newline = ';\n', header='data =[...', footer=']', comments = '#')
GROW = np.array(GROW)
np.savetxt('grow_dump.txt', GROW, fmt = '%10.12f', delimiter=',', newline = ';\n', header='data =[...', footer=']', comments = '#')
print(DOTS)
print(GROW)
```

Answer (score 2):

One way to optimize function grow:
"math.tan": the python interpreter search two times for this global and also must access math and than tan.
U could write a local Tan and set it to math.tan.

Simliar to ule*(TIME-TIME_FORM) this operation is done 5times

```
def grow(INDEX, TIME, TIME_FORM, PX, PY, ute, ule, alfa):
    tmp = ule*(TIME-TIME_FORM)
    TanAlfa = math.tan(alfa)
    X1 = PX + tmp
    Y1 = PY 
    X2 = X1
    Y2 = PY + TanAlfa
    X3 = X1
    Y3 = PY - TanAlfa
    if X2 < 1.5 and Y2 < 0.5 and Y3 > 0:    
        GROW.append([INDEX, TIME, TIME_FORM, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3])     
    return (GROW[:])
```

Comment: Thanks Benedikt! Will try this out and let you know how i go. Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

You are recopying `DOTS` and `GROW` at each iteration and then re-assigning it. As the lists grow, the copying operation (`GROW[:]`) can cost a lot and it does not seem you need it. Simply append the value and do nothing else. For instance for `GROW`

```
def grow(INDEX, TIME, TIME_FORM, PX, PY, ute, ule, alfa):
    ...
    if X2 < 1.5 and Y2 < 0.5 and Y3 > 0:    
        GROW.append([INDEX, TIME, TIME_FORM, X1, Y1, X2, Y2, X3, Y3])     
        # no return needed
```

And

```
for j in range(len(DOTS)):
    ...
    INDEX = TIME_FORM/DT
    grow(INDEX, TIME, TIME_FORM, PX, PY, ute, ule, alfa)
```

Same thing for `DOTS`.

Comment: Thanks Sebastien! Will try this out and let you know how i go. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

Another small improvement is to use xrange instead of range. Here you can read more:
https://wiki.python.org/moin/PythonSpeed/PerformanceTips#Use_xrange_instead_of_range

Comment: Thanks! Will try this also out and let you know how i go. Thanks!